# Sound Juicer could not read the cd

Tags: sound-juicer

I;m running Kubuntu 20.04. When I run Sound Juicer, I get the messages
Sound Juicer could  not read the CD.
Sound  juicer could not read the track listing on this CD.
Reason: The specified location is not mounted.

Yet I can read the CD with VLC without difficulty.

How can I get around this?

Comment: All the info I can find about this program says it is quite old. At least 5 to 10 years out of date. Are you sure it runs on this OS?

Comment: @David GNOME CD ripper Soundjuice is still in the repos in the latest Ubuntu, version 3.38, so sure it is not deprecated.

Comment: Ubuntu version 3.38?

Comment: 3.24 in Ubuntu 20.04 repos so it is still under development. Check this old bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sound-juicer/+bug/627008 and try the solutions starting on comment #23

Comment: Thanks, `gio mount cdda://sr0` worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS